# Filter data on client side js in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, js, es6

I have list of data like below format

```
   {
      "Category__c":"SUV",
      "Control__c":"Automatic",
      "Description__c":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ",
      "Fuel_Type__c":"Diesel",
      "Id":"a055g000009Qr1iAAC",
      "Make__c":"Ford",
      "MSRP__c":100000,
      "Name":"Ford ecosport",
      "Number_of_Seats__c":4,
      "Picture_URL__c":"/resource/1694268139000/carImages/ford_ecosport.png"
   },
   {
      "Category__c":"SUV",
      "Control__c":"Automatic",
      "Description__c":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ",
      "Fuel_Type__c":"Diesel",
      "Id":"a055g000009Qr1jAAC",
      "Make__c":"Ford",
      "MSRP__c":900000,
      "Name":"Ford endeavour",
      "Number_of_Seats__c":6,
      "Picture_URL__c":"/resource/1694268139000/carImages/ford_endeavour.png"
   },
   {
      "Category__c":"Hatchback",
      "Control__c":"Manual",
      "Description__c":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ",
      "Fuel_Type__c":"Petrol",
      "Id":"a055g000009Qr1kAAC",
      "Make__c":"Ford",
      "MSRP__c":857600,
      "Name":"Ford figo",
      "Number_of_Seats__c":4,
      "Picture_URL__c":"/resource/1694268139000/carImages/ford_figo.png"
   },
   {
      "Category__c":"Sedan",
      "Control__c":"Manual",
      "Description__c":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ",
      "Fuel_Type__c":"Diesel",
      "Id":"a055g000009Qr1lAAC",
      "Make__c":"Honda",
      "MSRP__c":345678,
      "Name":"Honda city",
      "Number_of_Seats__c":4,
      "Picture_URL__c":"/resource/1694268139000/carImages/honda_city.png"
   },
   {
      "Category__c":"Hatchback",
      "Control__c":"Manual",
      "Description__c":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ",
      "Fuel_Type__c":"Petrol",
      "Id":"a055g000009Qr1mAAC",
      "Make__c":"Honda",
      "MSRP__c":567567,
      "Name":"Honda jazz",
      "Number_of_Seats__c":4,
      "Picture_URL__c":"/resource/1694268139000/carImages/honda_jazz.png"
   },
   {
      "Category__c":"SUV",
      "Control__c":"Automatic",
      "Description__c":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ",
      "Fuel_Type__c":"Petrol",
      "Id":"a055g000009Qr1nAAC",
      "Make__c":"Honda",
      "MSRP__c":238909,
      "Name":"Honda wrv",
      "Number_of_Seats__c":6,
      "Picture_URL__c":"/resource/1694268139000/carImages/honda_wrv.png"
   },
   {
      "Category__c":"SUV",
      "Control__c":"Automatic",
      "Description__c":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ",
      "Fuel_Type__c":"Petrol",
      "Id":"a055g000009Qr1oAAC",
      "Make__c":"Hyundai",
      "MSRP__c":897987,
      "Name":"Hyundai creta",
      "Number_of_Seats__c":6,
      "Picture_URL__c":"/resource/1694268139000/carImages/hyundai_creta.png"
   },
   {
      "Category__c":"Hatchback",
      "Control__c":"Automatic",
      "Description__c":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ",
      "Fuel_Type__c":"Diesel",
      "Id":"a055g000009Qr1pAAC",
      "Make__c":"Hyundai",
      "MSRP__c":234678,
      "Name":"Hyundai grandi10",
      "Number_of_Seats__c":4,
      "Picture_URL__c":"/resource/1694268139000/carImages/hyundai_grandi10.png"
   },
   {
      "Category__c":"Sedan",
      "Control__c":"Manual",
      "Description__c":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ",
      "Fuel_Type__c":"Petrol",
      "Id":"a055g000009Qr1qAAC",
      "Make__c":"Hyundai",
      "MSRP__c":100300,
      "Name":"Hyundai venue",
      "Number_of_Seats__c":4,
      "Picture_URL__c":"/resource/1694268139000/carImages/hyundai_venue.png"
   },
   {
      "Category__c":"Hatchback",
      "Control__c":"Automatic",
      "Description__c":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ",
      "Fuel_Type__c":"Diesel",
      "Id":"a055g000009Qr1rAAC",
      "Make__c":"Hyundai",
      "MSRP__c":683899,
      "Name":"Hyundaii hyundaii20",
      "Number_of_Seats__c":4,
      "Picture_URL__c":"/resource/1694268139000/carImages/hyundaii20.png"
   },
   {
      "Category__c":"Sedan",
      "Control__c":"Automatic",
      "Description__c":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ",
      "Fuel_Type__c":"Petrol",
      "Id":"a055g000009Qr1sAAC",
      "Make__c":"Renault",
      "MSRP__c":344553,
      "Name":"Renault arkana",
      "Number_of_Seats__c":4,
      "Picture_URL__c":"/resource/1694268139000/carImages/renault_arkana.png"
   },
   {
      "Category__c":"Hatchback",
      "Control__c":"Manual",
      "Description__c":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ",
      "Fuel_Type__c":"Petrol",
      "Id":"a055g000009Qr1tAAC",
      "Make__c":"Renault",
      "MSRP__c":347880,
      "Name":"Renault kwid",
      "Number_of_Seats__c":4,
      "Picture_URL__c":"/resource/1694268139000/carImages/renault_kwid.png"
   },
   {
      "Category__c":"SUV",
      "Control__c":"Automatic",
      "Description__c":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ",
      "Fuel_Type__c":"Diesel",
      "Id":"a055g000009Qr1uAAC",
      "Make__c":"Renault",
      "MSRP__c":987987,
      "Name":"Renault triber",
      "Number_of_Seats__c":4,
      "Picture_URL__c":"/resource/1694268139000/carImages/renault_triber.png"
   },
   {
      "Id":"a055g000009QszkAAC",
      "Name":"Renault duster",
      "Picture_URL__c":"/resource/1694268139000/carImages/renault_duster.png"
   }
   ]
```

and a filtering condition as:

```
   {
   "filterConditions":{
      "searchkey":"ford",
      "selectedPrice":"1000000",
      "makeSelection":"Hyundai,Honda,Renault",
      "categorySelection":"Hatchback,Sedan,SUV"
   }
}
```

and an array that contains which fields to search in the list

```
searchableFields=['Name','Category__c','Make__c','MSRP__c']
```

I want to do a filter based on the filterCondition passed using an arrow function

```
getFilterdData(filterCondions){
        console.log('Filter condition :',filterCondions)
        console.log('Searchable Fields condition :',this.searchableFields)
        this.carLists=[...this.fullcarLists]
        this.carLists=this.carLists.filter(item=>{
            return this.searchableFields.some(field=>{
                if(field=='Name'||field=='Category__c'||field=='Make__c'){
                   return item[field].toLowerCase().includes(filterCondions.filterData.searchkey) 
                    
                }
            })
        })

    }
```

But unable to make a selection with all the conditions provided. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Could you add some context about how you are trying to use the filtered list, and what issue(s) you are seeing?

Comment: I am getting a list of data that I am assigning in a variable in the getFilterdData method. I have a filteredConditions which is basically a javascript Object which has few properties that may or may not have values. If any of the properties in filteredConditions object are not provided it will return the original list. If property values are provide in the filteredConditions  object , it will basically do a filter in the provided list of data and return only those data that satisfies the conditions. The searchableFields provides which fields to filter on the list of data.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but I'm assuming that you have a full list of data in `this.fullcarLists`, you want to filter it using your `getFilterdData()` function, and that you will then display it in your LWC by passing the filtered list to another LWC, such as `lightning-datatable`.  It's not clear where your `filterConditions` come from; I'm just going to assume they are available and could be stored in a component level variable.

LWC is a reactive framework; you should try to organize your code to work reactively.  For something like filtering a list of data, you are better off using a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to do the filtering; that way when the filter conditions change, the framework will automatically update the UI.  Here's an outline; you'll need to expand this based on your full code.

Javascript:

```
export default class FiltererViewer extends LightningElement {
    // assign these however you need to
    columns; // for the datatable in the example; omit if not using lightning-datatable
    fullcarLists;  
    filterConditions;
    searchableFields=['Name','Category__c','Make__c','MSRP__c'];

    get carLists() {
        return this.fullcarLists.filter(item=>{
            return this.searchableFields.some(field=>{
                if(field=='Name'||field=='Category__c'||field=='Make__c'){
                   return item[field].toLowerCase().includes(this.filterConditions.filterData.searchkey) 
                    
                }
            })
        })
    }

}
```

html:

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable
        key-field="id"
        data={carLists}
        columns={columns}>
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

The key point here is that the function `getFilterdData()` is now a getter named `carLists` that just returns the filtered data; the template can now reference the getter just as it would a variable named `carLists`.  Also note that the getter references only properties of `this`; if any of those properties (like `fullcarLists` or `filterConditions`) should change, the value of `carLists` will reactively change and any UI element that uses the list (like the datatable in my example) will also change.

Also, I suspect your filtering logic could be refined; my answer assumes it is correct and focuses on how to use that logic in an LWC.

Comment: I'd advise against using a getter. The LWR only detects changes on properties that are bound to the template. Getters don't meet that qualification and so may not work correctly.

Comment: @sfdcfox Interesting, I use this pattern all the time and have never had an issue.  Am I misunderstanding this?  "If a field’s value changes, and the field is used in a template or in a getter of a property that’s used in a template, the component rerenders and displays the new value."  From https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reactivity-fields.html

Comment: I wrote up an [example that demonstrates the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/salesforce-lwc-z2zlhj). It so happens that most components are complicated enough that this isn't an issue, but is something to be aware of. The documentation, therefore, is either misleading or wrong, depending on one's interpretation.